# Entering text into input field often requires two clicks for Jquery event to be triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I've created a click event handler that, when a search button is clicked/tapped after search text is entered into a text input field, populates a div with content. The code works fine on mobile devices, but on PCs, it seems to require two (or more) clicks. I can manually circumvent this issue by either a) Clicking on a blank region of the page until the text input field loses focus or b) Move my mouse cursor onto and off the search button several times. Obviously this is unacceptable, but I am completely mystified.

Here is a sample 19 line HTML file that reproduces this issue. To be clear, it seems to work fine on phones. Thanks in advance for any guidance that is offered!

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pb_btn").click(function(e){
        $("#pixabay_content").html(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000));
    });
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input id="id_meme_pixabay_search" type="text" name="meme_pixabay_search"><br>
<button id="pb_btn" type="button" name="pb" value="wtf" class="form_btn">Search</button>
<div id="pixabay_content"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. Always populates the element on the first click for me.

Comment: make sure `ids` are unique on your page. There should not be any other element with `pb_btn` as id

Comment: CertainPerformance, I would very much like to substitute your reality for my own, it's borked on both Chrome and Edge on my laptop :(

Comment: Works ok for me too.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll test this on other laptops at my house; it's presently breaking on my circa 2018 Alienware 17 running Windows 10. It even breaks when I run the code snippet from this page.

Comment: It seems like your PC hardware has issues or kind of too hard for a soft click.

Comment: Is there any third party scripts you have added?

Answer (score -1):

Turns out there's an app running on my laptop that is breaking mouse events. It works fine on other PCs. Thanks everyone for helping me break through my roadblock :)